# Contains method returns always false?

Tags: android, kotlin, collections, contains

i am fetching contacts and adding to a list.list contains duplicate contacts too,i have to remove duplicate contacts at the time of adding to list.

i am using contains method at the time of adding to list but contains method always returns false even there is same element in list.

```
if (!phoneContactVOList.contains(contactVO)) {
    contactVO.ContactName = name
    contactVO.ContactNumber = phoneNumber

    phoneContactVOList.add(contactVO)
}
```

here above code i am trying to add only unique contacts in list but duplicate contacts also adding.

Comment: Does contact class override equals method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the `equals(...)` method and write your custom implementation that returns true if the `name` and the `phoneNumber` are the same. 
For example like this:

```
override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
           if(other == null || other !is ContactClassObject)
               return false
           return name == other.ContactName && phoneNumber==other.phoneNumber
        }
```

Comment: You dont compare the contact object with the contacts list. You loop through the list and compare each list item namely a contact object to your comparable contact object. If you cant get a grip on it, ask this question in a new thread.

Answer (score -2):

You are setting values in **contactVO** object if your arraylist does not contains this. 
What are the values for each variable of **contactVO** while checking contains method? 
You can't do like this. You need to check one specific variable for each arraylist item to make decision, should it add into or not.
Go through loop and then check phone number if does not match then add into list.
Follow below code,

```
boolean insert = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < phoneContactVOList.size(); i++){

        if (phoneContactVOList.get(i).ContactNumber.equals(phoneNumber)){

            insert = false;

            break;
        }
    }

    if (insert){
        //set phoneContactVOList variable values
        phoneContactVOList.add(contactVO);
    }
```

*## Before starting loop you need to set insert variable value false*

Comment: melanzane's solution is the good one. Here, you just kind of recreate the `contains` method by yourself.